# Hardware acceleration in Chrome causes serif web fonts to stop working

Tags: google-chrome, webfonts

I have included some fonts in .woff format locally and everything works fine in Firefox and Edge. Only in Chrome, serif fonts are not displayed and the default font is output.

**After a few tries, I found that the problem can be solved by disabling "hardware acceleration" in Chrome settings.**

After disabling hardware acceleration, the serif font is displayed in Chrome without any problems.

Does anyone have any ideas what causes this issue? In my eyes, it is not due to the code or configurations but is only due to Chrome, because Chrome settings fix the problem. But now it is difficult to explain to potential visitors that it is not a website or code problem.

Any experience or ideas here?

I'm glad to have found the cause finally after lots of research, but unfortunately it's not a real solution. I want to make sure that locally embedded fonts in `woff` format always work without problems on all browsers.